# how can I make a copy the same value on char pointer(its point at) from char array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am using char array to store data when using fscanf function, as there is no space to malloc the char* before the function. However, I need it to be pointer for next function as the input is set as char pointer. How can I do it?

(Does it actually make sense?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `foo` is of type `char[n]` for integral `n`, then you can use

`&foo[0]`

to give you the pointer to the zeroth element of `foo`. The type of this expression is `char*`.

Comment: `+foo` works too, and in nearly all contexts `foo` as well.

Comment: Indeed. Although I've found that compilers issue warnings for such cases; I don't think I've come across one that warns you about `&foo[0]` even with warnings set to the maximum. Happy to be corrected on this though.